# Java versions confusion

Tags: java, deployment

I want to install Java on a few different servers for running a third party service on tomcat.
I am not a Java developer and I got a bit confused when I began searching for the installer.

I checked the different Java versions and their long term support dates.
It seems that Java 11 JDK is - LTS so i decided to use it.
But when I was trying to find a runtime version (JRE?) since this is the version I am supposed to install on the server(?) I only found Java JRE 8.X.X, and this got me confused.

There is no higher major version of the JRE?
How does it work if you use the JDK 11 or even 14-15 as a developer and then use Java 8 JRE on your deployed servers?

Maybe the JDK holds inside of it the Java 8 JRE version?
Or do you actually need to install the JDK version on the servers instead?

Comment: JRE is a runtime environment for Java virtual machine. JDK is a development kit for developing Java apps. Most of the JDK jars are present in JRE so there's no need to install JDK on servers. You should simply ship all your dependencies (except those that present in JRE) together with your app and put them into your app's classpath

Comment: there could be exceptions however (for example if you use Java server pages i.e. JSP then the runtime will have to compile them into bytecode but there is no compiler in the JRE, it's a part of JDK)

Comment: @mangusta  so if I understand this correctly the latest Java JRE which is 1.8.x.x should be fine in must cases and if someone developed an app with the latest JDK the needed 'components' will be must likely included in the latest JRE as well? So that I shouldn't be confused by the versions gap between JDK and JRE(?)

Comment: The JRE is no longer generally packaged separately.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- So If I want the latest java version on my servers//machines I should simply install the JDK version? From what I saw Java JDK 11 is the highest with Long-Time-Support, so I will install it?

Comment: Java JDK 11 is what most business projects I see are going with right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research,

It seems there is no separate JRE section anymore.
Also JDK 11 for production is not free and I guess this is an ongoing trend for the near future.

On a side note there is the open JDK 11 version but it does warn you about outdated security updates.

So basically in my case sticking to updated Java JRE 8 version is good enough for the near future.

Answer (score 1):

The JRE is a subset of JDK. It contains everything needet to run Java applications but no support for development. So, if you need a JRE, a JDK is also good, although it conatins much stuff that you will not need.

Normally, for executing a Java application, you need a JRE with the same version or higher than the JDK used for development. But the developer can advise the compiler to generate code for a lower version. If he does so, he cannot use the features of the higher versions. For example the compiler of JDK 1.8 can produce code for JRE 1.6. You should consult the manual, to see which old versions are supported by the compiler of a specific version.

Comment: Is it possible that from JDK 11 and going forward there is no JRE subset which I can install?
So that now I actually need to install the JDK on the servers and not the JRE (which does not exist as a standalone anymore)?

Comment: As a developer I noramlly install the complete JDK. For example on the site of Adopt DK there is only the complete JDK. Maybe there is an option for a minimal installaion when you install. Otherwise you can use the full JDK,